# I noticed that my MySQL slave's DB size is smaller than the Master's DB

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.6, replication

I have a very simple setup of a master MySQL DB with one slave MySQL DB replicating from it.

Initially, when setting up the slave, I used mysqldump to get an initial DB dump from the master like this :

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --master-data  some_db > someSQL.sql
```

Then I go to my slave DB, created a brand new DB named "some_db" and then tried to reverse dump:

```
 mysql -uroot --one-database some_db < someSQL.sql
```

But then I did a comparison of the DB sizes on the MySQL prompt and noticed that the master's some_db's size is around 7.6 gigs, but that of the slave's is only 6.4gigs.

I find this is concerning because I am wondering if certain data got lost. From what I understand, the DB does not contain blobs or any triggers, so where did that missing 1.2 gigs probably go?

Please let me know what your thoughts are.

Thanks
IS

Comment: how did you find the size in mysql prompt? data_length+index_length in information_schema.tables? If yes, then first you need to understand concepts of fragmentation and garbage collector.

Comment: I used this SQL query to find the sizes :

    SELECT table_schema                                        "DB Name", 
   Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM   information_schema.tables 
GROUP  BY table_schema;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tables go through many INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE cycle, mysql doesn't reclaim the space from deleted rows; instead, it internally flags the row as 'deleted' and leaves it in the tablespace. 1G size difference is not uncommon and shouldn't cause alarm.

You can try and run `optimize table` command on master and verify the table size get reduced. It is a good practice to routinely optimize table that does a lot of DELETE operation.

Comment: That's a good advice, Manny, I will try that and let you know if that explains the 1 gig difference, thanks